# Which browsers support Window's Low Integrity level?

Tags: windows, software-rec, browser, accessibility, dpi

Normally i like running **ie**, but it's rendering speed at high-dpi is *poor*.

More recently i've switched to **Chrome**, but it [does not support high-dpi displays](https://superuser.com/questions/32855/how-to-make-google-chrome-honor-my-windows-dpi-setting). i'm interested in trying other browsers, but they must [support protected mode](https://superuser.com/questions/30668/how-to-run-firefox-in-protected-mode-i-e-at-low-integrity-level).

Are there any other browsers, besides **IE** and **Chrome**, that support **Mandatory Integrity Levels** (i.e. *protected mode*)?

Browsers that i know about:

```
Browser            Protected Mode   High-dpi Aware
==============     ===============  ==============
Internet Explorer      Yes              Yes
Chrome                 Yes               No
Firefox                 No               No
Opera                   No               No
Safari                  No*              No*

(* not personally tested, reported by others)
```

Are there any others?

---

And just as an fyi, the clear, unambiguous, non-argumentative, non-subjective, question is:

> Are there any browsers, aside from Internet Explorer, available for **Windows**, that run at the Windows Low **Mandatory integrity level**, and support **high-dpi** (i.e. non-96 dpi) displays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try Internet Explorer 9 Beta.

Comment: i am. And while the fixed the high-dpi rendering speed (as well a javascript performance), they made a lot of negative changes that will keep me from using it.

Comment: @Ian: Such as..? I'm just curious what they did wrong.

Comment: Indeed. By "negative changes", do you mean things that actually make it act more standard (which could confuse sites that sniff for IE...), or?

Comment: @musicfreak: i was referring to user interface changes. Plus there are many usability features in Chrome that i've discovered i cannot live without. But the biggest issue is that IE lacks an extension API; which is preventing a port of AdBlock. i've used Chrome so long that when i tried IE9 beta i was jarred by the sheer volume of ads on the internet - and obnoxious ones, too.

Comment: @Ian Boyd: Fair enough. I haven't used IE9 yet so I was curious.

Answer (score 1):

Purely in the interest of providing a POTENTIAL alternative, you can screw around with Opera to make it do both of those things.

Low Integrity Level: I found a site that experiments with this

```
icacls %programfiles%\opera\opera.exe /setintegritylevel L
```

This sets the executible to run at LI, but it wont run.

```
icacls %UserProfile%\appdata\local\opera\opera /setintegritylevel (OI)(CI)L
```

It runs, but cannot retain preferences

```
icacls %AppData%\opera\opera /setintegritylevel (OI)(CI)L
```

And now it retains most preferences.

I found that [here](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showthread.php?t=283375)

As for high-DPI display, if you enter opera:config there is a "force DPI" setting, you can set it higher than 96 and see how things look. Perhaps worth a try!

Comment: This mirrors a question i asked about how to run FireFox in protected mode (http://superuser.com/questions/30668/how-to-run-firefox-in-protected-mode-i-e-at-low-integrity-level). It has the same issues as Opera. Unfortunately, to be truly usable the browser needs to be designed from the ground up with low rights users in mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
icacls %UserProfile%\appdata\local\opera\opera /setintegritylevel (OI)(CI)L

icacls %AppData%\opera\opera /setintegritylevel (OI)(CI)L
```

Apart from these you need to remove `NoWriteUp (-nx)` from these folder. you can use `chml.exe` for that

I use `chml <folder> -i:l -nx`
when using `chml.exe` you have to use one of `-nx -nw` or `-nr` else it is taken as `-nw`. So I use `-nx` to prevent `-nw` and `-nr`.

Works well for me but a couple of seconds delay in starting Opera and an additional application launch security warning.